# Python type metaclass __call__() method

Tags: python, metaprogramming

The type meta class in Python has a `__call__()` method. And the same method is used to create object of a class and for a class. For example:

```
class Animal:
    pass
```

In creating an object **for** the class Animal (in the notion that every class is stored as an object), the `__call__()` method is invoked. And similarly when we create an instance **of** the Animal class (i.e:  `Animal()` ), the same `__call__()` method invoked. I am trying to understand how the same method handles it.. could someone please throw the pseudo code of the `__call__` method.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`__call__()` is called when your class instance is called like:

```
animal = Animal()
animal()
```

It could be return any value of any type.

Maybe you are confused about the `__init__()` that are literally the constructor of a class and should always return `None`.

So if you want to execute anything on constructor use `__init__` and if you want to execute something like `instance(args)` you should use `__call__` method to do your thing